# How do I connect my consent screen to my google data studio connector?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm building a connector for google data studio. 
When adding a connecctor you're asked to first authorize it via google and are shown a consent screen. I've setup my consent screen in the oath2 console  (https://console.developers.google.com). 
Though I'm not sure how to let google data studio use my consent screen I've created in the console.

Currently it shows like this:

[image: Current oauth screen]

*Similar to what'd I'd like*
[image: Example]

Anyone had experience with this? Maybe its something set in the manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure the OAuth consent screen for your Data Studio [Community Connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/):

1. Attach your connector Apps Script project to a [Standard GCP Project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#standard_cloud_platform_projects).
2. [Configure the OAuth consent screen](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849) for your GCP project.